# Better way to debug a Node Cannot GET error?

Tags: node.js

I recently upgraded our app from Node v0.10.40 to Node v6.10.2. The app itself loads (minus certain images) but as soon as I click on any links on the page I get the above error. In one case its: Cannot GET /dashboard.html

I'm struggling to figure out exactly where this is occurring. I thought it was the server.js. Here is some code from there:

```
 var express = require('express'),
     masterConfig = require('./conf/config'),
     logger = require('./lib/logger'),
     restUtils=require('./lib/rest-utils');

 var app = express();
 app.set('views', __dirname+ '/views');
 app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
 app.get('/', function(req,res) {
    res.render('index.ejs', {contextPath: masterConfig.contextPath});
 });
 app.get(restUtils.buildUrl('/'), function(req,res) {
    res.redirect('index.html');
 });
 logger.info("Did I get here?");
 app.get(restUtils.buildUrl("/dashboard.html"), function(req,res) {
     res.render("dashboard", {contextPath: masterConfig.contextPath});
     });
```

My logger statement just above that last app.get doesn't seem to log out... so maybe its not making it into the server.js to call dashboard? 
Just looking for some ideas on how to better figure out where this error is coming from. So far nothing is showing up in any of the logs I have.

Thanks to @JJJ's tip... console.log wrote out on server startup, but did not write when I clicked on the dashboard link. So I guess that's being called somewhere else.

thanks!

Comment: What does `buildUrl` do?

Comment: What does `logger.info` do? Maybe try replacing it with good old `console.log`. Also note that the file is evaluated only once when the server starts, not at every request.

Comment: Wow... a downvote? For what?!?!

Comment: this is all buildUrl does (this is not my code, I inherited it). Also... sorry I cant seem to figure out how to format a comment:  exports.buildUrl = function(suffix) { return urljoin(config.contextPath, suffix);